# position following <div> left of preceding <div>

Tags: css

I've got two `div`s next to each other and would like to position the second `div` to the left of the first `div`. I can't change the order of these `div`s.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NvmUm/) to illustrate what I have.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NvmUm/2/

```
display: inline-block;
```

and using float.

Comment: Would need to be handled in IE7 as inline-block doesn't work in IE7

Comment: True, you could set an explicit width for #container `IF lte IE7`

Comment: That would be my preferred answer I think, definitely prefer inline-block where possible.

Comment: Great answer! Any pointers you can recommend to educate myself why this works like it does?

Comment: Honestly, I really don't. I've been a web programmer for awhile and I supposed it just sort of made sense one day. Twitter bootstrap has a lot of interesting features dealing with CSS. Other than that practice practice practice.

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:right` to the first div, `float:left` to the second, and limit the width of the container to the total width of the children

http://jsfiddle.net/NvmUm/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use positioning. Have both the div's position as absolute.
The second one's left as 0 and the first one's left as 100px;

```
position:absolute;
left:102px; //whatever needed
```

for both the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can add float:right both main and  thumbs. But you may need to add a third outer div in order to position these two.

```
#container {
    background-color: lavender;

}
#outer {
    float:left;
    width:400;
}
#main {
    border: 2px solid green;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    float:right;
}

#thumbs {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    float:right;
}
​

<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="outer">
                <div id="main">
                    1st div
                </div>
                <div id="thumbs">
                    2nd div
                </div>
            <div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```